# How to find if a Tab is already opened in Vaadin and setting it active instead of creating a new one

Tags: vaadin

In Vaadin, once you have a TabSheet, and some tabs are already opened, you don't want the same Tab, containing the same content to be opened many times.
How can I check that a Tab is already opened and set it to as the selected one?

Comment: give us some code sample of what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Vaadin's TabSheet checks by default, if a component already dded by comparing the component's hashcode.

It means you have to implement the method hashCode() in the component you want to add to the TabSheet.

Answer (score 3):

Using iterator in tab component, and compare with name.

```
Iterator<Component> i = tabSheet.getComponentIterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        Component c = (Component) i.next();
        Tab tab = tabSheet.getTab(c);
        if (name.equals(tab.getCaption())) {
            tabSheet.setSelectedTab(c);
            return;
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

In new Vaadin it could be solved in this way:

```
Component component = //...
for (Component c : tabSheet) {
    if (c.equals(component)) {
        // duplicate...
    }
}
```

But as @CRH mentioned before, you should take care of `equal()` and `hashCode()` correctness.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it could be done as follow:

```
Component cmp = /*you component with a description*/;


for (Component c : tabSheet) {
 if (c.getDescription().equals(cmp.getDescription())) {
     System.out.println("Equals Equals");
     return;
 }


}
```